# Is it worthwhile to Big Query in realtime XML Data?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an xml file around 2 MB (Yes !! 2MB small file), I want to sort the file in some predetermined format, and show the formatted result, as of not it takes 2 - 3 seconds for the whole process, we want to cut down on the time.

My Questions, are 
(a) Any way to directly push XML into big query instead of CSV.
(b) I would want to do realtime, so how do i push data from my website, and get the data back on my website. (Do you think the command line would do the tricks ?
(c) I am working on .NET.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can push XML directly into BigQuery. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide#importingatable) doesn't say, "You cannot import XML." But the fact that it only explains how to use CSV makes it pretty clear.

It doesn't sound like a perfect use case for BigQuery. BigQuery is great for huge data volumes, but you have small data (as you noted). Would it not be quicker to just sort your XML in memory without pushing it somewhere else?

Comment: Plus the big query jobs are asynchronous and can stay in pending state for a while so its probably not going to improve on response time. In fact for a task this small very few things other than a better algorithm are going to bring down response times.